# jQuery (change image)

Tags: jquery, menu

I have this HTML:

```
<dt id="hs-nav-ChapterIII">
<a href="/" class="hs-nav"><img src="/images/icons/tree_plus.gif"></a>
 <a href="/display/ChapterIII">Chapter III - The title of this chapter</a>
</dt>
```

I would want that when someone clicks the first link (which is containing an image with a + picture), that the source of the images changes to an image with a minus sign.

```
/images/icons/tree_minus.gif
```

Can anyone help me with this? I tried for a couple of hours already, with information that I can find on the JQUERY website but I cannot get it working.

How to do this? Which jQuery function?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.hs-nav').click(function(){
 var $img = $(this).find('img');
 var newsrc  = $img.attr('src').replace('plus', 'minus');
 $img.attr('src', newsrc);
 return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".hs-nav > img").attr("src", "/images/icons/tree_minus.gif");
```

Is one way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use .toggle()

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/